# Unable to redirect to php page using jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-mobile

Below is my html using jQuery Mobile:

```
<div class="ui-input-btn ui-btn ui-btn-b">
    Database Management
    <input data-enhanced="true" value="Enhanced - Theme swatch B" type="button" id="dbmgmt"></div>
```

And this is my script:

```
<script>
    $('#dbmgmt').click(function(){
        window.location.href='dbmgmt.php';
    })

</script>
```

However when I clicked on that button, it does nothing at all. What is my mistake?

Comment: Try adding the script in dom ready handler `jQuery(function () {
    $('#dbmgmt').click(function () {
        window.location.href = 'dbmgmt.php';
    })
})`

Comment: check your browser console to check whether there are any errors.... also make sure that there is only one element with the said id

Comment: @ArunPJohny `.ready()` should not be used to attach event in jQM.

Answer (score 2):

You first need to bind `click` on `pagecreate` event. And then use `change` function to move to that page.

Refrain from using `.ready()` in  to bind events in jQuery Mobile, use *page* events designed for jQuery Mobile framework.

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", function () {
  $('#dbmgmt').on("click", function () {

    $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", "dbmgmt.php");

  });
});
```

Make sure *Ajax Navigation* is enabled and place this code in `head` tag.

Comment: Can u explain further about refraining from using `.ready()`?

Comment: @yvonnezoe jQM uses _Ajax_ to load pages into DOM. When you use `.ready()`, it fires once and attach events to elements currently in DOM. But when you load new pages/elements using _Ajax_ into DOM none of them will receive any event listener.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, make sure you've loaded jQuery and jQuery mobile with correct path and order (include jQuery core first)

Secondly, try to wrap your code inside DOM ready `$(function(){ });`:

```
  $(function() {
      $('#dbmgmt').click(function(){
          window.location.href='dbmgmt.php';
      })
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Make it proper & try this,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#dbmgmt').click(function(){
        window.location.href='dbmgmt.php';
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$('#dbmgmt').on('click',function(){
    window.location.href='dbmgmt.php';
});

</script>
```

try this on 'click' event

Answer (score -1):

You can try this

```
$(function() {
  $('#dbmgmt').live('click',function(){
      window.location.href='dbmgmt.php';
  });
});
```

Comment: what's the difference between with and without "live"

Comment: some time .click() not works for me but when I use .live('click', function(){}); then it works.